# SwiftUI TextField Number Input

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I'm trying to have the user input two numbers and then have those numbers be displayed and also added together.  At the moment in order for the state variable to be updated you have the press return.  Is there a way to have the state update like it does with text?  I also have had the code inputed as a string but haven't been able to convert that to int so the numbers can be added together correctly. If anyone knows how to have it convert properly I would appreciate all the help I can get.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var numOne: Int = 0
    @State private var numTwo: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        TextField("Number One", value: $numOne, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)

                        TextField("Number Two", value: $numTwo, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }

                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: addedView(numOne: $numOne, numTwo: $numTwo),
                        label: {
                            Text("Navigate")
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct addedView: View {
    @Binding var numOne: Int
    @Binding var numTwo: Int
    @State private var added: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(numOne)")
            Text("\(numTwo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the problem that you want to display the numbers as they update live? Or something to do with how you display them in the destination of the `NavigationLink`?

Comment: @George I'm trying to get the textfield to either accept the numbers entered as an int or to convert the string that is inputed into an int.  I'm trying to add the two numbers entered from the user together but when I do it as a string it just places the numbers together rather then adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows how to enforce the `TextField`s be integers, and how to add them together for a result.

The main difference is that the formatter's `numberStyle` is `.decimal`. This means you will only get whole numbers / integers.

The result is added while they are `Int`s, so the **numbers** are added. If you add when they are both `String`s, they will **concatenate** together. E.g. you want `5 + 10` to be `15`, not `510`.

You can then pass the `result` to a child view or `NavigationLink` if you wish.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var numOne: Int = 0
    @State private var numTwo: Int = 0

    private static let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        return formatter
    }()

    private var result: Int {
        numOne + numTwo
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Section {
                        TextField("Number One", value: $numOne, formatter: Self.formatter)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)

                        TextField("Number Two", value: $numTwo, formatter: Self.formatter)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }

                    Section {
                        Text("Result: \(result)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `NumberFormatter` is created statically, and only once. This is because it is quite expensive to create them, especially twice *every* render.

Answer (score 0):

This uses Combine to make sure that the text entered is a digit, and then changes it to an Int to use in computations. The return value is a closure that you can use to

```
struct EditableInt : View {

    var intString: String = ""
    var onChanged: (Int) -> Void

    init(_ int: Int?, onChanged: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
        if let int = int,
           let formattedInt = Formatter.numberFormatter.string(from: int as NSNumber){
            self.intString = formattedInt
        } else {
            intString = ""
        }
        self.onChanged = onChanged
    }
    
    @State private var editableInt: String = ""

    var body: some View {
            TextField(" " + intString + " ", text: $editableInt)
            .onReceive(Just(editableInt)) { newValue in
                let editableInt = newValue.filter { "0123456789".contains($0) }
                if editableInt != intString {
                    if let returnInt = Int(editableInt) {
                        onChanged(returnInt)
                    }
                }
            }
        .onAppear { self.editableInt = self.intString }
    }
}
```

The above is reusable, and is called from another view like this:

```
struct OtherView: View {

    @State var otherViewInt = 0

        var body: some View {
            EditableInt(otherViewInt) { newInt in
                otherViewInt = newInt
            }
        }
}
```